# How to delete an element from a list in scheme

Tags: scheme

how to delete an element from a list
ex:- list=[1 2 3 4]

I have come up with some code.I think I got wrong somewhere.

```
 (define delete item
   (lambda (list)
   (cond
    ((equal?item (car list)) cdr list)
     (cons(car list)(delete item (cdr list))))))
```

Answer (score 13):

Your code is almost correct.
The `item` also should be a parameter, so the function may begin with like this:

```
(define delete
  (lambda (item list)
  ...
```

Also, your code needs paren around the `cdr list` and `else` in the last clause.
Then, the code may be like this:

```
(define delete
  (lambda (item list)
    (cond
     ((equal? item (car list)) (cdr list))
     (else (cons (car list) (delete item (cdr list)))))))
```

Comment: delete so defined is not tail-recursive.

It could also be defined via fold/filter.

Comment: With this procedure, if the element occurs more than once, it just deletes the first one. There can be a procedure that deletes all same elements in list.

Comment: `(define (delete item list) (filter (lambda (x) (not (equal? x item))) list))`

Answer (score 5):

Shido Takafumi wrote a tutorial about Scheme, [Yet Another Scheme Tutorial](http://www.shido.info/lisp/idx_scm_e.html).
In [chapter 7](http://www.shido.info/lisp/scheme7_e.html), exercise 1, the 3rd problem.

> A function that takes a list (ls) and an object (x) as arguments and returns 
>   a list removing x from ls.

The author gave the solution code bottom of the page.

```
; 3
(define (remove x ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '()
      (let ((h (car ls)))
        ((if (eqv? x h)
            (lambda (y) y)
            (lambda (y) (cons h y)))
         (remove x (cdr ls))))))
```

The code maybe difficult to comprehend for beginner.
It's same as the code below.

```
(define (rm x ls)
  (if (null? ls)
      '()
      (if (eqv? x (car ls))
          (rm x (cdr ls))
          (cons (car ls)
                (rm x (cdr ls))))))
```

This can delete the same elements in list. :D

Answer (score 1):

1) if consider the input list may be a simple list, or you just want to delete the item in the top-level of a nested list
for example:

```
delete 2 from (1 2 3 4) will return (1 2 3)
delete 2 from (1 2 3 (2 3) 3 2 4) will return (1 3 (2 3) 3 4)
```

as we can see the 2nd example above, it just delete the item in the top-level of the nested list, within the inner list, we doesn't change it.

this code should be:

```
(define (deleteitem list1 item) 
( cond
    ((null? list1) ’())
    ((equal? (car list1) item) (deleteItem (cdr list1) item)) 
    (else (cons (car list1) (deleteitem (cdr list1) item)))
))
```

2) if consider the input list may be a nested list

for example:

```
input list: (1 2 3 (3 2 (2 4 (2 5 6) 2 5 6) 2 4) 2 3 (2 3 4))
```

and delete the element 2 in the input list

```
the output list should be: (1 3 (3 (3 (5 6) 5 6) 4) 3 (3 4))
```

and the code should be:

```
(define (delete2 list1 item) 
    ( cond
    ((null? list1) '())
    ((pair? (car list1)) (con (delete2 (car list1) item) (delete2 (cdr list1) item)))
    ((equal? (car list1) item) (delete2 (cdr list1) item)) 
    (else (cons (car list1) (delete2 (cdr list1) item)))
))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work just fine, but only deletes an element that should be in the list:

```
(define (delete element lst)
    (let loop ([temp lst])
        (if (= element (car temp)) (cdr temp)
            (cons (car temp) (loop (cdr temp))))))
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank @ad absurdum for pointing out my problems

delete element from a list without nested lists

---

bad code:

```lisp
(define (remove item lst)
  (define (filter-lst l)
      (cond
           ((null? l) nil)
           ((= item (car l)) (filter-lst (cdr l)))
           (else (cons (car l) (filter-lst (cdr l)))))
  )
  (if (null? lst) () (filter-lst lst))
)
```

```
;;; Tests
(remove 2 '(4 3 2))
; expect (4 3)
(remove 3 nil)
; expect ()
(remove 3 '(1 3 5))
; expect (1 5)
(remove 5 '(5 5 1 4 5 4))
; expect (1 4 4)
```

the code above tested in Berkeley CS61A scheme interpreter

---

```lisp
(define (remove item lst)
  (cond 
    ((null? lst) '())
    ((equal? item (car lst)) (remove item (cdr lst)))
    (else (cons (car lst) (remove item (cdr lst)))))
)
```

```
(remove 2 '(1 3 2))
; expect (1 3)
(remove 3 '())
; expect ()
(remove 3 '(1 3 5))
; expect (1 5)
(remove 5 '(5 3 5 5 1 4 5 4))
; expect (3 1 4 4)
```

the code above tested in chez scheme interpreter

Comment: Why do you wrap `filter-lst` in `remove`? You could just as well remove the inner function definition and use the `cond` expression by itself. Other than that, I see two problems. 1) `=` is for numbers; better to use `equal?` to handle other types as well. 2) Use `'()` instead of `nil`: `nil` is not in any Scheme standard since at least the mid 80's. This is implementation-dependent, at best. IIRC SICP used `nil` in places; maybe you were using a Scheme implementation custom tailored to work through SICP? Oh, 3 problems: you can't use `()` in Scheme, either. You have to quote it: `'()`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ad absurdum: thank you for pointing out my problems.

Answer (score -4):

```
(define (deleteItem(list item))
    (cond
    ((eq ? item (car(list)))cdr(list))
    (cons(car(list)(deleteItem(cdr list)))
    )
)
```