# Scheme remove a list

Tags: list, filter, scheme

I found the contents of this thread quite useful!
[How to delete an element from a list in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905222/how-to-delete-an-element-from-a-list-in-scheme/8331205#8331205)

I tested the code recommended, and it seems that it removes a single item at its first and only occurrence in the list.

Say instead I wanted to all occurrences of the item from the list. Or even further, if I wanted to specify a list of items instead of an item to remove.

For example if I had a function called `removelist` that took two lists as parameters

```
(define (removelist L M))

> (removelist '(1 2 2 3 4 5 2 2 5 6 7 8 9) '(1 2))
> '(3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9)
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: what's the result of `(removelist '(1 2 1 2 1 3 4 5) '(1 2 1))` ?

Comment: The result of that would be '(3 4 5).  Basically, it's removing all occurrences of items in list M, from list L.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple function that uses `filter` and `member` to accomplish this:

```
(define (remove-list l m)
 (filter (lambda (element)
          (not (member element m)))
  l))
```

Here the results:

```
> (remove-list '(1 2 2 3 4 5 2 2 5 6 7 8 9) '(1 2))
  (3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9)
> (remove-list '(1 2 2 3 4 5 2 2 5 6 7 8 9) '(1 2 1))
  (3 4 5 5 6 7 8 9)
```

This snippet requires `srfi-1`. Hope this helps.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: That's actually very helpful!!  Thank you so much.  How do filter and member work exactly though?

Comment: Check the documentation of [filter](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#filter) and [member](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#member). You can check other functions of the `srfi-1` [here](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#ProcedureIndex). Basically, `filter` returns every element that match the predicate (the lambda function passed to it). The function `member` returns the element if it is part of the list or `#f` if not.

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it is what you were looking for ;)

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, but unfortunately, not quite the answer I'm looking for.  This is part of a school assignment, and unfortunately, I'm not allowed to use srfi-1 or anything.  But if I can figure out how filter and member were written to implement myself, I'm sure that would be exactly what I need.  :)

Comment: Hey Matt, thanks again.  I was able to figure it out after finding some documentation regarding the use of `member`!  :)

Answer (score 0):

Using simple recursion and no built-in functions like filter or member:

```
(define (filter_out m l)
  (cond ( (null? l) '() )
        ( (equal? (car l) m) (filter_out m (cdr l)) )
        ( else (cons (car l)  (filter_out m (cdr l))) )
        ))
```

Test:

```
(filter_out 'jay (list 'jay 'z 'jay 'dilla 'jay 'electro))
(filter_out '(jay z) (list '(jay z) '(jay dilla) 'jay '(electro)))
```

If you're interested in learning this type of coding, check out "The Little Schemer." It takes only a few hours to read and you'll be a master at recursion after reading it.