# Scheme: How to delete/remove element from a vector

Tags: vector, scheme, gimp, script-fu

I'm starting scheme for Gimp script-fu and I don't find a simple way to remove item from a vector.

My only solution is to:

1. Convert vector to list
2. Remove item from the list (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905222/how-to-delete-an-element-from-a-list-in-scheme)
3. Convert list to vector

Is it a simplier way?

Here is my code:

```
(set! myvector (list->vector (delete item (vector->list myvector))))

(define delete
  (lambda (item list)
    (cond
     ((equal? item (car list)) (cdr list))
     (else (cons (car list) (delete item (cdr list)))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the way: you need to create a new vector without the element that needs to be removed, copying all the others. But in your code, you're missing the case where the element is *not* present in the vector, also you don't need to create an intermediate list, go from vector to vector directly. I wrote this with Racket using standard Scheme, it should be easy enough to adapt for script-fu:

```
(define (vector-delete vec elt)
  (let ((new-vec (if (> (vector-length vec) 0)
                     (make-vector (- (vector-length vec) 1))
                     (vector))))
    (define (loop i j)
      (cond ((= i (vector-length vec))
             new-vec)
            ((equal? (vector-ref vec i) elt)
             (loop (+ i 1) j))
            ((< j (vector-length new-vec))
             (vector-set! new-vec j (vector-ref vec i))
             (loop (+ i 1) (+ j 1)))
            (else vec)))
    (loop 0 0)))
```

Use it like this:

```
(define myvector #(1 2 3))
(set! myvector (vector-delete myvector 3))
myvector
=> '#(1 2)
```

Comment: OK, so I ve to recreate a brand new vector each time... why not. Thanks for your code it work perfectly without modification in Gimp :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or by a more intuitive way :

```
(define (vector-delete v i)
  (vector-append (vector-take v i) (vector-drop v (+ i 1))))
```