# Scheme: how to delete the element only in the second level of a list?

Tags: list, scheme, nested-lists

I have done with

1) [delete element for the top-level of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744865/3156777)

2) [delete element for a nested list no matter how deep the list is.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26744865/3156777)

But how to solve the problem below:

> Write a Scheme function that takes a list as a parameter and returns a list identical to the parameter list except with the second top-level element removed. If the given list does not have two elements, the function should return ().

And in this question, i don't know how to forbid the recursion into the 3rd-level and only delete the element in the 2nd level of the input list.

Comment: According to that description, you should remove the second top-level element regardless of what it is, unless there are fewer than two elements, in which case the result is `()`. There's no need to recurse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I take it you have a list `(a b c d)` where all symbols can be anything, even sublists. Your code needs to reduce this to `(a c d)`. Is that right?

Here is a hint:

```
(define (remove-2nd lst)
  (if (or (null? <??>)
          (null? <??>))
      <??>
      (cons <??> <??>)))
```

Comment: not the second element, but the second level, for example: delete the second level `2` element from the input `(1 2 3 (2 3 4) (2 3 (2 4 5) 4 5 2) 3 4 2 2 2)`, and it should return `(1 2 3 (3 4) (3 (2 4 5) 4 5) 3 4 2 2 2)` only the `2` in the second level nested list should delete, all the `2` in the top-level or lower level(compare to 2) should keep

Comment: @jyuan Your problem statement says "the second top-level element", not "an element from the second level".

Comment: @jyuan How I see it my answer matches your question. If you want what you wrote in the comment you need to edit your question to match that.